# I can't Pause my game in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, pause

I am trying to pause my game by touching a button. But I can't.

What is the easiest way to pause a game and continue?

Below is the my whole code. I know it's a mess but I am really new in this stuff.

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

    FlapAndFly faf = new FlapAndFly();
    SpriteBatch sb;
    Random rnd;
    Ucak player;
    BigBoss boss;
    float ani =1f;
    Vector2 vec;
    Rectangle ucakRect,upRect,downRect,mermiRect,fireRect,rightRect,leftRect,bossRect,bossMermiRect,tavanRect,tabanRect;
    Vector2 yercekimi  = new Vector2();
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2();
    Vector3 touchPoint;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    float x = 0;
    float boy;
    TextureRegion arka, arka1,arka2,arka3,arka4;
    Kayalar[] altkayalar = new Kayalar[50];
    Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[50];

    Kayalar[] ustKayalar = new Kayalar[50];
    Rectangle[] altRect  = new Rectangle[50];
    Rectangle[] ustRect  = new Rectangle[50];
    Rectangle[] enemyRect  = new Rectangle[50];

    Mermi tekMermi,bossMermi;
    Animation bomba;
    int skor = 0;
    Vector2 mermiVec;
    Vector2 bossMermiVec;
    Vector2 enemyVec;
    Vector2 bossVec;
    boolean dus=false;
    boolean playerDus = false;
    ShapeRenderer sr;
    boolean ates = false;
    boolean bossAtes = false;
    boolean doldur = true;
    float s= 0;
    boolean bom = false;
    public int a;
    boolean right = true, left = false, up = false, down = false, savas = false;
    boolean ucakBom = false;
    float playerGuc = 1;
    float bossGuc = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6;
    Music play = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("play.mp3"));


    Rectangle lazerRect,lazerbuttonRect,pauseRect;
    Lazer lazer;
    Vector2 lazerVec;
    boolean lazerAtes = false;
    Sound lSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("lazer.wav"));
    Sound gunSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("gun.wav"));
    Sound playerSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("heli.wav"));
    Sound bossSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("boss.wav"));
    boolean pause = false;


    public PlayScreen(FlapAndFly faf) {
        super();
        this.faf = faf;

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Dosyalar.yükle();
        play.setVolume(0.5f);
        play.play();
        playerSound.loop();

        sb = new SpriteBatch();
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
        rnd = new Random();
        bomba = new Animation(0.1f, Dosyalar.boomReg1,Dosyalar.boomReg2,Dosyalar.boomReg3,Dosyalar.boomReg4,Dosyalar.boomReg5);
        bomba.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        pos.x = 0;
        pos.y = 0;
        boy = 0;
        enemyVec = new Vector2(pos.x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 ,boy);
        player = new Ucak();
        player.ucakOlustur(0.03f, Dosyalar.ucak1Reg, Dosyalar.ucak2Reg, Dosyalar.ucak3Reg);

        for(int i = 0; i<altkayalar.length; i++){

            boy = rnd.nextInt((Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3));
            enemyVec.y = rnd.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2) + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4;
            ustKayalar[i] = new Kayalar(Dosyalar.kayaUstReg, pos.x+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,
                        Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-boy,  Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11, boy);

            altkayalar[i] = new Kayalar(Dosyalar.kayaReg, pos.x+Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), pos.y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11, boy);
            altRect[i] = new Rectangle(altkayalar[i].x + altkayalar[i].width /2 , altkayalar[i].y , altkayalar[i].width/18, altkayalar[i].height);
            ustRect[i] = new Rectangle(ustKayalar[i].x + ustKayalar[i].width/2, ustKayalar[i].y, ustKayalar[i].width/18, ustKayalar[i].height);
            enemy[i] = new Enemy(Dosyalar.enemyReg, enemyVec.x, enemyVec.y,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);        
            pos.x+=(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
            enemyVec.x+=(float) rnd.nextInt((int)(Gdx.graphics.getWidth())+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/3);

        }

        vec = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/30, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-(Dosyalar.ucak1Reg.getRegionHeight()/2));
        yercekimi.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/250, 0);
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());    
        mermiVec = new Vector2();


        bossVec = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*3/2);
        boss = new BigBoss(Dosyalar.heliReg1,Dosyalar.heliReg2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), 0.01f);

        bossMermiVec = new Vector2();
        boss.ucakOlustur();

        lazerVec = new Vector2(cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), cam.position.y- Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.arkaPlanReg, x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0,(float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), (float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.arkaPlanReg1, x, 0,(float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), (float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.arkaPlanReg2, x+Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0,(float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), (float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.arkaPlanReg3, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*2), 0,(float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), (float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.arkaPlanReg4, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*3), 0,(float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), (float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        sb.end();

                for(int i = 0; i < altkayalar.length; i++){

                    enemyRect[i] = new Rectangle(enemy[i].x, enemy[i].y,enemy[i].width,enemy[i].height);    

                    altkayalar[i].create(sb);
                    ustKayalar[i].create(sb);
                    altRect[i] = new Rectangle(altkayalar[i].x + altkayalar[i].width /2 , altkayalar[i].y , altkayalar[i].width/18, altkayalar[i].height);
                    ustRect[i] = new Rectangle(ustKayalar[i].x + ustKayalar[i].width/2, ustKayalar[i].y, ustKayalar[i].width/18, ustKayalar[i].height);
                }


        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ustReg, x-(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5),Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ustReg1, x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5),Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ustReg2, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5),Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ustReg3, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*2), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5),Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);        
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ustReg4, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*3), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5),Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);

        sb.draw(Dosyalar.altReg, x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.altReg1, x, 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.altReg2, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.altReg3, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*2), 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.altReg4, x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*3), 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5);

        sb.end();

        player.ucakCiz(sb, player.ucak.getKeyFrame(ani), vec.x, vec.y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

        for(int i = 0; i < altkayalar.length; i++){

            enemy[i].create(sb);
            enemy[i].gel(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/250);

            }

        sb.begin();

        sb.draw(Dosyalar.controlReg, cam.position.x - (float)(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4));        
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.fireReg,cam.position.x + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.ekranReg, cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8);
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.lazerReg,cam.position.x + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6));
        sb.draw(Dosyalar.pauseReg, cam.position.x  + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16 , cam.position.y + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9);
        sb.end();

        pauseRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x  + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16 , cam.position.y + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/16), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9);
        ucakRect = new Rectangle(vec.x+player.width/4, vec.y,player.width/3*2, player.height);
        bossRect = new Rectangle(boss.x, boss.y, boss.width, boss.height);

        upRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7));
        downRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7)); 
        rightRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10 ),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7));
        leftRect = new Rectangle (((cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7));

        tekMermi = new Mermi(mermiVec.x, ucakRect.y, ucakRect.width/8*3, ucakRect.height/8*3, Dosyalar.bulletReg);  
        bossMermi = new Mermi(bossMermiVec.x + ucakRect.width/8*3 , bossRect.y + ucakRect.height/8*3, ucakRect.width/8*3, ucakRect.height/8*3, Dosyalar.bossBulletReg);

        mermiRect = new Rectangle(tekMermi.x,tekMermi.y,tekMermi.width,tekMermi.height);
        fireRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6));

        bossMermiRect = new Rectangle(bossMermi.x,bossMermi.y,bossMermi.width,bossMermi.height);
        tavanRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, cam.position.y + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2- Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7 , Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7);
        tabanRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, cam.position.y - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/7);

        lazer = new Lazer(sr, lazerVec.x, lazerVec.y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 45, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        lazerRect = new Rectangle(lazer.x,lazer.y, lazer.width,lazer.height);
        lazerbuttonRect = new Rectangle(cam.position.x + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6));


        tekMermi.render(sb);
        bossMermi.render(sb);
        boss.ucakCiz(sb);

        vec.add(yercekimi); 


        for(int z = 0; z<2; z++){

            if (Gdx.input.isTouched(z)) {

            touchPoint = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(z), Gdx.input.getY(z),0);
            cam.unproject(touchPoint);
            }
        }



        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){

            if(pauseRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                pause = true;
            }

            if(fireRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                ates = true;
                doldur = false; 

            }

            if(lazerbuttonRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                if( playerGuc > 1){     

                    System.out.println("lazsrerr");
                    lazerVec.x = cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - lazer.width*3;
                    playerGuc -=5;
                    lazerAtes = true;

                        }
                else{



                    }
            }
        }

        if(pause){

            Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);

            }

        if(!pause){

            Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
        }

        if(lazerVec.x > cam.position.x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2){

            lazerAtes = false;
            lazerVec.x = cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

        }

        if(lazerAtes){

            lSound.play();
            lazerVec.add(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, 0);

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < enemy.length; i++){

            if(lazerRect.overlaps(enemyRect[i]))

            enemy[i].y = -200;

        }

        if(lazerRect.overlaps(bossRect)){

            bossGuc = bossGuc-5;
            System.out.println(bossGuc);
        }


        if(ates){

            mermiVec.x+=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20;

        } 

        if(mermiVec.x >= cam.position.x+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2+tekMermi.width){

            doldur = true;
            ates = false;
        }

        if(doldur){

            mermiVec.x = ucakRect.x+ucakRect.width/8;

        }

        if(dus){

            enemy[a].y -=15;
            enemy[a].x +=5;

        }

        for( int i = 0; i < enemyRect.length; i++){

            if(mermiRect.overlaps(enemyRect[i])){

                    skor+=1;
                    playerGuc +=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/800;
                    System.out.println("playerGuc :" +playerGuc);
                    enemyRect[i].width = 0;
                    enemyRect[i].height = 0;
                    enemyRect[i].y = 0;
                    doldur = true;
                    ates= false;
                    bom = true;
                    dus = true;
                    a = i;

                }
        }

        if(bom){

            sb.begin();

            sb.draw(bomba.getKeyFrame(s), enemy[a].x, enemy[a].y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

            sb.end();
            s+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            if(s > 2){

                bom = false;
                s = 0;
            }
        }

            cam.position.x += yercekimi.x;

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

            if(upRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                vec.y+=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/160;
                if(vec.y >= Gdx.graphics.getHeight() -  ucakRect.height){
                    vec.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() -  ucakRect.height;
                }
            }


            if(downRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){
                vec.y -=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/160;

                if(vec.y <= 0){
                    vec.y=0;
                }

            }
            if(rightRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                vec.x+=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/220;

                if(vec.x>cam.position.x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-ucakRect.width){

                    vec.x = cam.position.x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-ucakRect.width;
                }
            }
            if(leftRect.contains(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){

                vec.x-=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/220;

                if(vec.x < cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2){

                    vec.x = cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
                }
            }
        }

        cam.update();


        if(vec.x >= x+(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)){

            x+=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

        }

        if(mermiRect.overlaps(bossRect)){

            bossGuc -=playerGuc/5;

            System.out.println("bossGuc : " +bossGuc);
        }

        if(ucakBom){

            sb.begin();

            sb.draw(bomba.getKeyFrame(s), ucakRect.x, ucakRect.y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

            sb.end();

            s+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            System.out.println(s);

            if(s > 2){

                ucakBom = false;
                s = 0;

                }
            }

        if(playerDus){

            vec.y-=5;

            if(vec.y<0){
                play.stop();
                playerSound.stop();
                bossSound.stop();
                faf.setScreen(new GameOver(faf));   
            }
        }


        for(int j = 0; j < altkayalar.length; j++){

            if(ucakRect.overlaps(altRect[j]) || ucakRect.overlaps(enemyRect[j]) || ucakRect.overlaps(ustRect[j])){

                play.stop();
                playerSound.stop();
                bossSound.stop();
                faf.setScreen(new GameOver(faf));

            }
        }

        if(ucakRect.overlaps(bossRect) || ucakRect.overlaps(bossMermiRect) || ucakRect.overlaps(tavanRect) || ucakRect.overlaps(tabanRect)){

        ucakBom = true;
        playerDus = true;

    }

        if( boss.x - vec.x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-199){

            yercekimi.set(0,0);
            savas = true;
        }

        if(savas){
        Savas();
        }

        if(bossGuc < 0){

            play.stop();
            playerSound.stop();
            bossSound.stop();
            faf.setScreen(new Clear1(faf));

        }
        ani+=delta;

        sr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        sr.rect(cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()- Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/17 , playerGuc,  Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/22);
        sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        sr.rect(cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 +  Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() -  Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8, bossGuc, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/22);
        sr.end();


    }

    public void PauseGame(){        



    }

    public void Savas(){

//      bossSound.loop();

        if(boss.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-boss.height){

                up = false;
                down = true;    
            }

        if(boss.y < 0){

                down = false;   
                up = true;
            }

        if(boss.x < cam.position.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/3){

            right = true;
            left = false;

        }

        if(boss.x > cam.position.x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - boss.width){

            left = true;
            right = false;

        }

        if(down){

            boss.Down();
        }

        if(up){

            boss.Up();

        }

        if(right){

            boss.Right();
        }

        if(left){

            boss.Left();
        }

        if(bossRect.y %93 == 0){

            bossAtes = true;

        }

        if(bossAtes){

            bossMermiVec.x-=20;
        }

        if(!bossAtes){

            bossMermiVec.x = bossRect.x;
        }

        if(bossMermiVec.x < cam.position.x -Gdx.graphics.getWidth() -100){

            bossAtes = false; 
            }

        }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have a PlayScreen, you can also just make a PauseScreen. Just pass in all the information you want to save into the PauseScreen (player pos., score, etc.). When you go back to the PlayScreen, just give it all the original data back.

Another way of doing it would be by stopping all update methods like `render()` and just keeping the exact same instance of PlayScreen so you can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I am still relatively new (one year in coding overall), but I use the following for the game I am currently developing...
Modify the code to your needs and optimize it to your like. I cut off a lot of code to make it easier to understand.

```
public enum GAMESTATE{
    RUNNING, PAUSED, FAILED, PASSED;
}




    @Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.position.set(WORLD_WIDTH / 2, WORLD_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);

    // REST OF CODE

    gamestate = GAMESTATE.RUNNING;

    // REST OF CODE
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    switch (gamestate){

        case RUNNING:
            update(delta);
            renderRunning(delta);
            break;

        case PAUSED:
            renderPaused(delta);
            break;

        case FAILED:
            levelFailed();
            break;

        case PASSED:
            levelPassed();
            break;
    }
}




@Override
public void pause() {
    gamestate = GAMESTATE.PAUSED;
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    gamestate = GAMESTATE.PAUSED;
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    gamestate = GAMESTATE.PAUSED;
}




 private class PauseButton extends Actor {

    private Texture pause;

    private PauseButton(){
        pause = new Texture("button/pause.png");

        setWidth(150);
        setHeight(150);
        setBounds(1200, 2100, getWidth(), getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(buttonStage);
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                gamestate = GAMESTATE.PAUSED;
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(GameScreen.camera.combined);
        batch.draw(pause, 1200, 2100);
    }

    @Override
        public void act(float delta){
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(buttonStage);
    }
}






private class ResumeButton extends Actor {

    private Texture resume;

    private ResumeButton(){
        resume = new Texture("button/resume.png");

        setWidth(150);
        setHeight(150);
        setBounds(1200, 2100, getWidth(), getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(resumeButtonStage);
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                gamestate = GAMESTATE.RUNNING;
                PauseMenuActor.timer = 0;
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(GameScreen.camera.combined);
        if (gamestate == GAMESTATE.PAUSED) {
            batch.draw(resume, 1200, 2100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(resumeButtonStage);
    }
}
```

Use [Stage(libgdx API)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) to add the button actors

```
Stage stage, resumeButtonStage;

private void defineButtonStage(){
    // Pause Button Stage
    buttonStage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    buttonStage.setViewport(viewport);

    PauseButtonSprite pauseButtonSprite = new PauseButtonSprite();
    buttonStage.addActor(pauseButtonSprite);


    // Resume Button Stage.
    resumeButtonStage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    resumeButtonStage.setViewport(viewport);

    ResumeButtonSprite resumeButtonSprite = new ResumeButtonSprite();
    resumeButtonStage.addActor(resumeButtonSprite);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to handle this is by creating a GameStateManager class that handles all your different states, it will make it possible for you to switch from a PlayState (Screen) to a PauseState.

GameState Design Info: http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/game-state-management/